# Why sometimes my geofence on android doesnt work unless the phone is restarted

Tags: android, kotlin, location, geofencing, android-geofence

im doing a project that using geofence, i wrote my code in kotlin, when im testing it, its worked perfectly, but on next day, it doesnt work, i need to restart my phone to get the geofence work (the transition triggered), can u help me guys?

i dont use broadcast receiver but using the intentservice, also i plan this to run on background

MainActivity.kt

```
    private lateinit var mGeofencingClient: GeofencingClient
    private var mGeofenceList: ArrayList<Geofence> = ArrayList()

    private val geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest
        get() {
            return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
                setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                addGeofences(mGeofenceList)
            }.build()
        }

    private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        mySharedPreferences = MySharedPreferences(applicationContext)
        mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
        removeGeofences()

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
        val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
        val lastUpdateGeofence = mySharedPreferences.getLastUpdateGeofence()
        if (currentDate != lastUpdateGeofence){
            presenter.requestDataForGeofence(dataUser.userId)
        }
    }

    override fun onFetchOutletSuccess(data: MainResponse) {
        populateGeofenceList(data.result)
    }

    override fun toastError(error: String) {
        toast(error)
        Log.d("MainActivity", error)
    }

    private fun populateGeofenceList(data: List<Schedule>) {
        mGeofenceList.clear()
        for (schedule in data) {
            mGeofenceList.add(
                Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(schedule.name)
                    .setCircularRegion(
                        schedule.latitude.toDouble(),
                        schedule.longitude.toDouble(),
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build()
            )
        }
        addGeofences()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun addGeofences() {
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            toastError(getString(R.string.insufficient_permissions))
            return
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding Geofences")
        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, geofencePendingIntent).run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                toastError("Success adding Geofence")
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                val errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this@MainActivity, it)
                toastError(errorMessage)
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun removeGeofences() {
        mGeofencingClient.removeGeofences(geofencePendingIntent).run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                toastError("Success removing Geofence")
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                val errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this@MainActivity, it)
                toastError(errorMessage)
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
```

TransisitionIntentService.kt

```
class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService : IntentService(TAG) {
    private lateinit var detail: String

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            val errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.errorCode)
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            return
        }

        val geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            val triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences

            val geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences)
            when (geofenceTransition) {
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER -> {
                    detail = "$geofenceTransitionDetails"
                    sendNotification(detail)

                }
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT -> {
                    detail = "$geofenceTransitionDetails "                                  sendNotification(detail)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition))
        }
    }

    private fun getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            geofenceTransition: Int,
            triggeringGeofences: List<Geofence>): String {

        val geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition)

        val triggeringGeofencesIdsList = ArrayList<String>()
        for (geofence in triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.requestId)
        }

        val triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList)

        return "$geofenceTransitionString: $triggeringGeofencesIdsString"
    }

    private fun getTransitionString(transitionType: Int): String {
        when (transitionType) {
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER -> return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered)
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT -> return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited)
            else -> return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition)
        }
    }


    private fun sendNotification(notificationDetails: String) {
        val mBuilder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(
                applicationContext,
                "notify_001"
            )
        val ii = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, ii, 0)
        val bigText = NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()

        bigText.bigText(notificationDetails)
        bigText.setBigContentTitle("Apps")
        bigText.setSummaryText("Notification")

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Apps")
        mBuilder.setContentText(notificationDetails)
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText)

        val mNotificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val channelId = "Your_channel_id"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId)
        }
        val int = (Date().time / 1000L % Int.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
        mNotificationManager.notify(int, mBuilder.build())
    }

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you fix this issue? I am facing the same issue, can you please share the detail about your finding. thanks!

Comment: @milanmanvar i didnt use geofence anymore.. i comparing the distance of 2 marker